# Remote Partitioning : Worker side serialization issue

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

When running worker getting below exception
I have used org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer and org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer which is working at the master side correctly , but getting exception at worker side ..... at the last i get Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'handler'; defined in: 'batch.configuration.WorkerConfiguration'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.StandardMethodMetadata@7f811d00']; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize data [StepExecution: id=5, version=93, name=workerStep:partition4, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=31, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=] for topic [reply], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=StepExecution: id=5, version=93, name=workerStep:partition4, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=31, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=, headers={sequenceNumber=1, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@454b7395, sequenceSize=10, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_replyTopic=reply, kafka_receivedTopic=requests, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@454b7395, kafka_offset=5, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1a6c92e3, kafka_correlationId=[B@ef1f7b2, correlationId=1:workerStep, id=49d312f5-618f-5085-fad1-7868e8e06aa0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1603368744168, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = requests, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 5, CreateTime = 1603368744168, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 64, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = sequenceNumber, value = [49]), RecordHeader(key = sequenceSize, value = [49, 48]), RecordHeader(key = correlationId, value = [49, 58, 119, 111, 114, 107, 101, 114, 83, 116, 101, 112]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_replyTopic, value = [114, 101, 112, 108, 121]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 83, 105, 122, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 114, 114, 101, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 95, 114, 101, 112, 108, 121, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_replyTopic, value = [114, 101, 112, 108, 121]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_correlationId, value = [-127, -49, 126, 33, 100, 99, 79, -14, -81, -35, -70, -88, -61, 37, 61, -63])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=1, stepExecutionId=5, stepName=workerStep]), kafka_groupId=repliesGroup, timestamp=1603379041885}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1887) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1792) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1719) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1617) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1064) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'handler'; defined in: 'batch.configuration.WorkerConfiguration'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.StandardMethodMetadata@7f811d00']; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize data [StepExecution: id=5, version=93, name=workerStep:partition4, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=31, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=] for topic [reply], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=StepExecution: id=5, version=93, name=workerStep:partition4, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=31, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=, headers={sequenceNumber=1, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@454b7395, sequenceSize=10, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_replyTopic=reply, kafka_receivedTopic=requests, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@454b7395, kafka_offset=5, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1a6c92e3, kafka_correlationId=[B@ef1f7b2, correlationId=1:workerStep, id=49d312f5-618f-5085-fad1-7868e8e06aa0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1603368744168, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = requests, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 5, CreateTime = 1603368744168, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 64, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = sequenceNumber, value = [49]), RecordHeader(key = sequenceSize, value = [49, 48]), RecordHeader(key = correlationId, value = [49, 58, 119, 111, 114, 107, 101, 114, 83, 116, 101, 112]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_replyTopic, value = [114, 101, 112, 108, 121]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 83, 105, 122, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 114, 114, 101, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 95, 114, 101, 112, 108, 121, 84, 111, 112, 105, 99, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_replyTopic, value = [114, 101, 112, 108, 121]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_correlationId, value = [-127, -49, 126, 33, 100, 99, 79, -14, -81, -35, -70, -88, -61, 37, 61, -63])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=1, stepExecutionId=5, stepName=workerStep]), kafka_groupId=repliesGroup, timestamp=1603379041885}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1902) [spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'handler'; defined in: 'batch.configuration.WorkerConfiguration'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.StandardMethodMetadata@7f811d00']; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize data [StepExecution: id=5, version=93, name=workerStep:partition4, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=31, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=] for topic [reply]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.
```

Code of worker

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@EnableIntegration
@ImportResource("context.xml")
public class WorkerConfiguration {

    private final RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory;
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory;

    @Autowired
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public WorkerConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.workerStepBuilderFactory = workerStepBuilderFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (requests coming from the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (replies going to the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    /*
        protected JobRepository createMyJobRepository() throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setTransactionManager(new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
            factory.setDataSource(createDataSourceForRepository());
            factory.setDatabaseType("HSQL");
            return factory.getObject();
        }


        public DataSource createDataSourceForRepository() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url("jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/hsqldb/batchcore.db;hsqldb.lock_file=false;shutdown=true;")
                    .driverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
                    .username("sa")
                    .password("")
                    .build();
        }


        public DataSource createDataSourceForRepository() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bdauser")
                    .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                    .username("bdauser")
                    .password("bdauser")
                    .build();
        }



        @Bean
        public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
            return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(createDataSourceForRepository()) {
                @Override
                public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
                    JobRepository jobRepository = null;
                    try {
                        jobRepository = createMyJobRepository();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("************************WORKER  replying Inside  batchConfigurer    ****************");
                    return jobRepository;
                }
            };
        }

    */


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "replies")
    public MessageHandler handler() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("************************  worker inside serviceactivator **********************");
        KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
        handler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression("reply"));
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
         return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }


        @Bean
        public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
            ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(new TopicPartitionOffset("nullChannel", 0));
            System.out.println("************************** WORKER  ContainerProperties   *****************************");
            containerProperties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
            return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
        }


        @Primary
        @Bean
        public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory, KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer) {
            System.out.println("**************************WORKER  replying Template Templet  *****************************");
            ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingKafkaTemplate = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory,repliesContainer);
            replyingKafkaTemplate.setSharedReplyTopic(true);
            Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(50);
            replyingKafkaTemplate.setDefaultReplyTimeout(d);
            return replyingKafkaTemplate;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {
            System.out.println("**************** worker node ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer  *****************************");
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer = containerFactory.createContainer("requests");
            repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("repliesGroup");
            repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
            repliesContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
            return repliesContainer;
        }


        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow serverGateway(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container, KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
            return IntegrationFlows
                   .from(Kafka.inboundGateway(container, template)
                   .replyTimeout(3000000))
                   .channel(requests())
                   .get();
       }


        @Bean
        public Job remotePartitioningJob() {
            System.out.println("*******************  inside  remotePartitioningJob **************************");
            return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("remotePartitioningJobMy")
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(workerStep())
                    .build();
        }

        /*
         * Configure the worker step
         */
    @Bean
    public Step workerStep() {
        System.out.println("*******************  inside  worker step **************************");
        return this.workerStepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
                .inputChannel(requests())
                .outputChannel(replies())
                .tasklet(tasklet(null))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['partition']}") String partition) {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            System.out.println("processing " + partition);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler partitionHandler() throws Exception {
        MessageChannelPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new MessageChannelPartitionHandler();
        partitionHandler.setStepName("slaveStep");
        partitionHandler.setGridSize(10);
        partitionHandler.setMessagingOperations(messageTemplate());
        partitionHandler.setPollInterval(5000l);
        partitionHandler.setJobExplorer(this.jobExplorer);
        partitionHandler.afterPropertiesSet();
        return partitionHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public MessagingTemplate messageTemplate() {
        MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate(outboundRequests());
        messagingTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(60000000l);
        return messagingTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public ExecutorChannel outboundRequests() {
        return MessageChannels.executor("outboundRequests", new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).get();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("************************WORKER   CONFIGURATION    ****************");
        SpringApplication.run(WorkerConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

property File

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=cdh5161-e2e-test-1.eaas.amdocs.com:9092,cdh5161-e2e-test-2.eaas.amdocs.com:9092,cdh5161-e2e-test-3.eaas.amdocs.com:9092,cdh5161-e2e-test-4.eaas.amdocs.com:9092,cdh5161-e2e-test-5.eaas.amdocs.com:9092,cdh5161-e2e-test-6.eaas.amdocs.com:9092,cdh5161-e2e-test-7.eaas.amdocs.com:9092,cdh5161-e2e-test-8.eaas.amdocs.com:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=remotePartitioningConsuerGroup

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.add.type.headers=false 

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
server.port=8050

## PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bdauser
spring.datasource.username=bdauser
spring.datasource.password=bdauser

#drop n create table again, good for testing, comment this in production
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: Adding details: getting this exception when the worker side producer sending the response in reply Kafka topic. Property used for this is ByteArraySerializer for key and org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer for value

Comment: Aren't there more logs for that `Can't serialize data` to determine the reason why it cannot be serialized? Probably the object you try to serialize as a JSON is not compatible...

Comment: Have you tried increasing the stack size?

Comment: Tries to put more logs here ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488339/serialization-issue-in-spring-batch-remote-partitioning-stackoverflow-exceptio
Logs are very huge .. cant provide all

Comment: In logs it can be seen its failing for payload of generic message , and at master side with the same way it was able to process generic message .

Answer (score -1):

Because you're using json.StepExecution class and JobExecution class have bi-directional relationship. So it causes the infinite recursion while trying to serialize the StepExecution object to send back to reply channel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).